# MIME::Lite error attaching file perl

Tags: perl, email, mime

500 Internal server error when attaching a file, but not when sending without attachment.

```
    use MIME::Lite; 


$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    =>'email@domain.com',
    To      =>'email@domain2.com',
    Subject =>'A message with 2 parts...',
    CC      => '',
    Type    =>'TEXT',
    Data    =>'Thank you for your interest in'
);

    ### If I comment out the following attachment code the email sends OK, otherwise i get 500 internal server error

$msg->attach(
    Type     =>'image/gif',
    Path     =>'/images/tree.gif',
    Filename =>'tree.gif',
    Disposition => 'attachment'
)or die "error attaching file\n"; 



$msg->send;
```

Comment: You'll have to check your web server logs for the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion and a few things I can recommend for this also. Applying this method will allow you to `split` your text/html parts and attachments to include, so you can send a message with multi attributes if you would like.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Lite; 

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        To      => 'email@domain2.com',
        From    => 'email@domain.com',
        Subject => 'A message with 2 parts...',
        Type    => 'multipart/alternative',
);

# Make my text part
my $txt = MIME::Lite->new(
        Type => "text/plain",
        Data => 'Thank you for your interest in',
);

# Make my html part
my $html = MIME::Lite->new(
         Type => 'multipart/related',
);

# Here you can attach what html tags you would like to include.
$html->attach(
     Type => 'text/html',
     Data => "<b>my html is here</b>",
);

$html->attach(
     Type => 'image/gif',
     Id   => 'tree.gif',
     Path => "../images/tree.gif",
); 

$msg->attach($txt);
$msg->attach($html);

my $data = $msg->as_string;
```

Also I seen where you were using `die` for error handling, no need to do that here.

Answer (score 0):

The error ended up being in that the URI has to be written relative to the script.

So I had to change `/images/tree.gif`

To

`../images/tree.gif`

Comment: URI? It's a path. Of course you can use an absolute path here, but it does have to be valid.